# I can't connect to my MongoDB server from remote

Tags: mongodb

As title.
I can connect to the DB when my computer are in the same LAN with my server. However, I can't connect to the DB when I am not in the same LAN with my server.

I've tried anything I can do but nothing helped. Can anyone helps me, plz.
My server was build on Windows 10. I used studio 3T in my laptop(win 10)

What I've already done:

1. set the bindIP to 0.0.0.0
2. confirmed that mongodb is running correctly
3. open port 27017 in firewall
   --
   Sorry for my bad grammer, I'm not really good in English.
   If you need any info to answer, just let me know !
   Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: could you make telnet to mongodb ?

Comment: You said "open port 27017 in firewall". Is this your network firewall? The local firewall may block it also.

Comment: @mohammadNaimi Yes, I can telent to mongodb when I'm in LAN.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not sure which firewall I've opened. I opened the 27017 port in Windows Defender.

Comment: did you add username for connecting to MongoDB ?

Comment: Windows Defender is what I mean by local firewall. In Linux it would be `firewalld`. What is the error message you get?